# RecursiveDirectoryIterator Show Folder First

Tags: php

I'm using RecursiveDirectoryIterator to show files from a path:

```
$pasta = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/files/";

$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($pasta, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

$dir  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

$dir->setMaxDepth(1);

foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) { 
 echo $fileinfo->getFilename()."<br/>";
}
```

This show all files and folder in Alphabetical order, Is there a way to show first folders than files in Alphabetical order?

Comment: Was looking to see if flag could be set to just retrieve files, then directories. Not seeing it. Also, think it just makes more sense to get it all, store into an array (`isFile`/`isDir`), then sort as you desire.

Comment: Additionally. I am not sure the result order is something I would even trust. Might depend on filesystem / OS... implementation of `opendir()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `isDir` method to separate directives from files.

```
$pasta = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/files/";

$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($pasta, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

$dir  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

$dir->setMaxDepth(1);

$dirs  = [];
$files = [];
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if($fileinfo->isDir())
        $dirs[] = $fileinfo->getFilename(); 
    else
        $files[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
}
$result = array_merge($dirs,$files);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);

echo implode('<br>', $result);
```